# SAS not recognizing date format

Tags: string, sas, character, numeric, informat

I have the following character date format:

```
"3/1990"
"4/1990"
"5/1990"
...
```

I tried the following code:

```
data work.temps;
  set indata;
  newdate = input(strip(Date), MMYYSw.);
  rename newdate = date;
run;
```

I keep on getting the following error meassage: `Informat MMYYSW was not found or could not be loaded.`

Comment: You might try `MMYYS.` in place of `MMYYSw.`. See if that makes any difference

Comment: No I get the same error

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may have to use a different informat to read in the character dates so that SAS can interpret them as numeric (since dates in SAS are actually numeric values), and then format them as `MMYYS.`.

This was tested and works for me:

```
DATA temps;
FORMAT newdate MMYYS.;
SET indata;
newdate = INPUT(COMPRESS('01/'||date),DDMMYY10.);
RUN;
```

Comment: Thank you. I will say that your answer does make a nice distinction between FORMAT and INFORMAT.

Answer (score 3):

Try this with anydtdte:

```
data have;
    input date $10.;
    _date=input(compress(date,'""'),anydtdte.);
    format _date MMYYs7.;
    cards;
    "3/1990"
    "4/1990"
    "5/1990"
    ;
    run;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you refer is a FORMAT, not INformat.
You'll use format with PUT function, for INPUT, you need informat.

Anyway I didn't find a suitable informat to be used directly, so you'll need to do more stuff:

```
data work.temps;
infile cards truncover;
input Date $10.;
newdate=MDY( scan(Date,1, '/'), 1, scan(Date,2, '/') );
cards;
3/1990
4/1990
5/1990
;
run;
```

SCAN takes Nth word from a string, MDY creates DATE from Month, Day and Year.
The code above gives the first day of the month.